# JQuery Plugin for img:hover Descriptions

Tags: jquery

I am designing a website and need to make it so that hovering over an image will dim it and display a description over it and a link. I know I saw a JQuery plugin for this, before, but cannot seem to be able to find it again? It seems to be used by a lot of people, so I am wondering if anyone can provide a link to the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of plugins for image overlays:
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/30-text-captions-overlay-image-plugins/